# SQL how to do 1 hour interval

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql query which returns record by date specified
What I want to  do is group them by 1 hour interval 
My query returns a date and interval.
interval value looks like this 
8:00,8:30,9:00,9:30,10:00
as you can see the interval has produce 5 value what I want to do is group them by this
8:00-9:00,9:00-10:00

I have designed a query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,VC.DATE+ VC.INTERVAL) AS DATE
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL) AS INTERVAL 
      FROM VMUK_Q1R_IB_CONSOLIDATED VC
```

But the problem with this it display like this 8,8,9,9,10
How to I achieve this?

Comment: what types are VC.DATE and VC.INTERVAL ?

Comment: VC.DATE IS DATETIME and VC.INTERVAL IS VARCHAR(5)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create a set of hourly values and join back to it based on the hour part of your value. This will make sure the missing 'buckets' are represented. The following CTE will give you the lookup for 24 hours - you could do the same thing with a static lookup table too.

```
with ranges 
as 
(
select 0 as value
union all 
select r.value+ 1 from ranges r where r.value <= 24
)
select 
r.value start
from ranges r
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by a calculation or formatting.  I think formatting would be simpler for this example.  Try this:

```
SELECT Convert(VarChar(20), DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL)) + ':00' AS DATE
     ,DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL) AS INTERVAL 
FROM VMUK_Q1R_IB_CONSOLIDATED VC
```

If you want the full date + time shown, rounded down, try this:

```
SELECT Convert(VarChar(20), VC.Date, 101) + Convert(VarChar(20), DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL)) + ':00' AS DATE
     ,DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL) AS INTERVAL 
FROM VMUK_Q1R_IB_CONSOLIDATED VC
```

If you want time ranges too, try this:

```
SELECT Convert(VarChar(20), VC.Date, 101) + Convert(VarChar(20), DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL)) + ':00' AS DATE,
     ,DatePart(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL)) + ':00 - ' + DatePart(HOUR, DateAdd(HOUR, VC.INTERVAL, 1)) + ':00' AS TimeRange
     ,DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL) AS INTERVAL 
FROM VMUK_Q1R_IB_CONSOLIDATED VC
```

Comment: It just shows result of 8:00,8:00,9:00,9:00,10:00 What I want to do is Like this one column should contain like this 8:00-9:00,9:00-10:00

Comment: You can find the end of your interval by using DateAdd to add an hour to your start time.  I adjusted my example.

Comment: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR,VC.DATE+ VC.INTERVAL) AS DATE,
    case DATEPART(HOUR,VC.INTERVAL)
        when 0 then '00:00-00:59'
        when 1 then '01:00-01:59'
        .
        .
        etc.
        .
        .
        when 22 then '22:00-22:59'
        when 23 then '23:00-23:59'
    end AS INTERVAL 
FROM VMUK_Q1R_IB_CONSOLIDATED VC
```